# verified accounts on Youtube

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

How can I retrieve the list of verified accounts on youtube?
Any python/php/javascript code or any language support that could help me retrieve the list.

This work is related to my project.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: i have no idea 
how to proceed

Comment: You  have to try something atleast stackoverflow is there to help you fix problems/errors not to write your code

Comment: sorry but at least can you please give me a direction from where to start. this is a very small part of my project

Comment: There is no google api for verified accounts so you will not find if they are verified or not